# Toggle visability child on hover parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, onmouseover

I'd like to show my image caption (eg. Name of image) when I hover the figure.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail-grid flex">
    <a href="#" class="flex-item">
        <figure class="i1">
            <figcaption class="hide"> caption blabla
                <img src="img/view.png"/> 
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried to make a function in Javascript:

```
var text = document.querySelector('figcaption');

document.querySelector('figure').onMouseOver = function() {
    text.classList.remove('hide');
}

document.querySelector('figure').onMouseOut = function() {
    text.classList.add('hide');
}
```

In my CSS I set .hide to display: none; But my function doesn't work.

Can anybody help me out?

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/613/

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect. The image and caption should be siblings not parent/child.

Comment: You can do it with just css is it okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with jquery.

```
$(".caption").hide();
$(".flex-item").hover(function(){
$(".caption").toggle();
});
```

Caption is the class for figcaption. When you hover the flex-item the caption will be toggled.

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay i did it with just css see  http://jsfiddle.net/5qq9fz9r/

HTML

```
<div id="figure">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301"/>
<div id="name">NAME</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#name{
overflow:hidden;
height:0;
text-align:center;
top:0;
position:absolute;
background-color:black;
color:white;
width:300px;
transition:2s;
}

#figure img:hover ~ #name{
height:80px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Liked the cat haha

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.nnsheriff.org/img/placeholder/blogpost-placeholder-100x100.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.nnsheriff.org/img/placeholder/blogpost-placeholder-100x100.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    <figcaption>Fig2. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figcaption {
    display:none;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("figure").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find($("figcaption")).css("display", "block");
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        $(this).find($("figcaption")).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/872b5tw4/)

Comment: I tried this before, but when I used display: block; it didn't worked.